# Why do the guard in routing.module file blocks all the routes?,

Tags: angular, routes, guard

If i add provider's array to admin-routing.module i can't open any route defined in this module, but i've added only canActivate rule to only one, sub - path.

If i clean provider in admin-routing.module then i can get access to admin routes, except my chosen path with guard protection. But AuthGuard doesn't work correctly - dont navigate to fixed path ( it's obvious - i didnt register service so angular don't see it - i think so:) ).

And if i register AuthGuard in admin.module.ts then whole app don't run. I didn't try to register any other guard anywhere ( in app-routing.module.ts is no provider).

Here is admin-routing.module.ts:

```
const adminRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: AdminPanelComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "", redirectTo: "login", pathMatch: "full" },
      {
        path: "manage",
        component: ManageArticlesComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
          {
            path: "create",
            component: CreateArticleComponent
          },
          {
            path: "articles",
            component: ArticleListComponent
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "login",
        component: LoginComponent
      },
      {
        path: "signup",
        component: SignupComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(adminRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: [AuthGuard]
})
```

and here is my AuthGuard:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
  //method canActivate gets params: actual route and state. We always take it from this router objects as below.
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    // return true;
    if (this.authService.isAuth()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(["/admin/login"]);
      return false;
    }
    //isAuth method added to if statement returns true or false depends on is user logged in or registered in.
    //it need to return true or promise /(or) observable that resolve to true. in other case gets error.
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance to any idea, what is causing my issue.

Comment: Where is "admin" coming from in `navigate(["/admin/login"]);`

Comment: admin coming from main routing module - app-routing.module.ts, here is the code: 

`const routes: Routes = [  
  {  
    path: "",  
    loadChildren: () =>  
      import("./main-site/main-site.module").then(mod => mod.MainSiteModule)  
  },  
  {  
    path: "admin",  
    loadChildren: () =>  
      import("./admin-panel/admin-panel.module").then(  
        mod => mod.AdminPanelModule  
      )    
  },  
  { path: "**", component: ErrorComponent }  
];`

Comment: If i even return true it guard's canActivate method - there is still the same problem.

Comment: I will answer myself - the problem i found is that i didn't add decorator - @ before injectable() in AuthGuard class. So if any one has similar problem - check it also :)